# C# Unit Test - Prove that async methods in a Task.WhenAll() run asynchronously properly

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asynchronous

I have a method I want to test that has four methods which run asynchronously. I would like to have a unit test that proves they run in parallel. I am not sure how to do this, and unable to find anything online.

Here's an example of what I have

Method I am trying to test

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<ReturnData>> GetData()
{
    List<ReturnData> returnData = new List<ReturnData>();

    Task<IEnumerable<ReturnData>> dataTypeA = dataServiceA.GetDataTypeA();
    Task<IEnumerable<ReturnData>> dataTypeB = dataServiceB.GetDataTypeB();
    Task<IEnumerable<ReturnData>> dataTypeC = dataServiceC.GetDataTypeC();
    Task<IEnumerable<ReturnData>> dataTypeD = dataServiceD.GetDataTypeD();

    await Task.WhenAll(dataTypeA, dataTypeB, dataTypeC, dataTypeD);

    returnData.AddRange(dataTypeA.Result);
    returnData.AddRange(dataTypeB.Result);
    returnData.AddRange(dataTypeC.Result);
    returnData.AddRange(dataTypeD.Result);

    return returnData;
}
```

My Unit Test

```
[TestMethod]
public async Task GetDataTestAsync()
{

    mockedDataServiceA.Setup(a => a.GetDataTypeA())
        .Callback(() => Thread.Sleep(1000))
        .ReturnsAsync(mockedDataA);

    mockedDataServiceB.Setup(a => a.GetDataTypeB())
        .Callback(() => Thread.Sleep(1000))
        .ReturnsAsync(mockedDataB);

    mockedDataServiceC.Setup(a => a.GetDataTypeC())
        .Callback(() => Thread.Sleep(1000))
        .ReturnsAsync(mockedDataC);

    mockedDataServiceD.Setup(a => a.GetDataTypeD())
        .Callback(() => Thread.Sleep(1000))
        .ReturnsAsync(mockedDataD);

    IDataService dataService = new DataService(mockedDataServiceA.Object,
                                            mockedDataServiceB.Object,
                                            mockedDataServiceC.Object,
                                            mockedDataServiceD.Object,);

    DateTime startTime = DateTime.Now;
    IEnumerable<ReturnData> data = await dataService.GetData();
    DateTime endTime = DateTime.Now;

    TimeSpan timeDiff = endTime.Subtract(startTime);

    Assert.IsTrue(timeDiff.TotalSeconds < 4);
}
```

I have tried using both `Thread.Sleep(1000)` and `Task.Delay(1000)`

Neither give the desired result. I would expect the test to run for just over 1 second since each method should run in parallel.

When using `Thread.Sleep(1000)` the test runs for 4.1 seconds (fails the test)

When using `Task.Delay(1000)` the test runs in less than 100ms. Which would technically pass the test with the Assert I have, but is not the desired result.

I know the methods truly do run in parallel when I am running my web service, I just was wanting to have a unit test to prove out that functionality, and also protect that functionality if there are any code changes in the future.

Comment: Set a bool at the start of each Task, then check whether all 4 bools are set after 100ms

Comment: FYI you could just do `returnData.AddRange(await Task.WhenAll(dataTypeA, dataTypeB, dataTypeC, dataTypeD));`  and I'd at least suggest doing `returnData.AddRange(await dataTypeA)` instead.

Comment: Use Task.Delay instead of Thread.Sleep, but instead of making your test method async, invoke your GetData method as `var result = dataService.GetData().Wait()` instead of `await dataService.GetData()` i.e. keep the test method synchronous.

Comment: @Zenilogix I will also try out your suggestion too. I did try Task.Delay already, but did not invoke the method the way you suggested yet. I will let you know of the results.

Comment: @juharr That would probably work in most cases, but I just gave an example of how my code was setup. There is a little bit of code after .AddRange() before I finally return the data. It was just not relevant to my question so I excluded it from my example code.

Answer (score 1):

Use TaskCompletionSource to control when the tasks get completed.

Note that this test assumes that the `GetDataAsync` calls return the first tasks that the method awaits. If the test awaits other tasks, then you'd need to ensure you don't call `mock.Verify()` until all of the `GetDataAsync` methods have been called, probably by decrementing a [CountdownEvent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.countdownevent?view=net-6.0) in the mock callbacks.

```
public class UnitTest1
{
    [Fact]
    public async Task Test1()
    {
        // TCS allows the test to control when the tasks complete
        // without needing to use Sleep or Delay (which will make the
        // test take unnecessarily long and probably introduces a race
        // condition)
        var (mockA, tcsA) = CreateMock();
        var (mockB, tcsB) = CreateMock();
        var (mockC, tcsC) = CreateMock();

        var service = new DataService(mockA.Object, mockB.Object, mockC.Object);

        var task = service.GetAllDataAsync();

        // Verify the method hasn't finished yet (AKA it's awaiting the tasks)
        Assert.NotEqual(TaskStatus.RanToCompletion, task.Status);

        // Verify that all the methods have been called
        mockA.Verify(m => m.GetDataAsync());
        mockB.Verify(m => m.GetDataAsync());
        mockC.Verify(m => m.GetDataAsync());

        // Now complete all the tasks and verify the method completes
        tcsA.SetResult(null);
        tcsB.SetResult(null);
        tcsC.SetResult(null);
        await task;
    }

    (Mock<IGetData>, TaskCompletionSource<object>) CreateMock()
    {
        var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<object>();
        var mock = new Mock<IGetData>();
        mock.Setup(m => m.GetDataAsync()).Returns(tcs.Task);
        return (mock, tcs);
    }
}

public interface IGetData
{
    Task<object> GetDataAsync();
}

class DataService
{
    private IGetData _serviceA;
    private IGetData _serviceB;
    private IGetData _serviceC;
    public DataService(IGetData serviceA, IGetData serviceB, IGetData serviceC)
    {
        _serviceA = serviceA;
        _serviceB = serviceB;
        _serviceC = serviceC;
    }

    public async Task GetAllDataAsync()
    {
        var taskA = _serviceA.GetDataAsync();
        var taskB = _serviceB.GetDataAsync();
        var taskC = _serviceC.GetDataAsync();

        await Task.WhenAll(taskA, taskB, taskC);

        // do something with results;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the info. I will try this out.